# Google Chrome Extension -- chrome.storage.sync.get not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just wondering if anyone can see anything wrong with my code, the saving of the data works fine, however when I try to load it, it cannot find the saved data:

Code:

```
$('#SaveSet').click(function() {
    var theValue = $('#col').val();
    if (!theValue) {
        alert('Error: No value specified');
        return;
    }
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'ToSave': theValue
    }, function() {
        alert('Settings saved' + " " + theValue);
    });
});
$('#Get').click(function() {
    alert('working');
    chrome.storage.sync.get("ToSave", function(data) {
      alert("data" + data);
    });
});
```

When I get the alert after trying to get the data, it reads "data[object Object]"

Comment: `console.log("data"+data)` would give the same `data[object Object]`.  But if you had done `console.log(data)`, it would have let you inspect the data object to see what was happening.

Comment: `alert` is such a useless debugging tool. Use `console.log` instead. Or better yet, set breakpoints. Btw don't concatenate strings in `console.log`, it's useless as well. Use `console.log(a, b, c,...)` instead

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `chrome.storage.sync.get` will always return to you an object, even if you're only asking for the value of a single key.

That would mean that instead of your `data` parameter being just the value, it is actually an object, with a single key named 'ToSave'.

Try this for your `#Get` handler:

```
$('#Get').click(function() {
    alert('working');
    chrome.storage.sync.get("ToSave", function(data) {
        alert("data: " + data.ToSave);
    });
});
```