# chrome.storage.sync.set isn't saving data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am storing an array `URLarry`, using chrome.storage.sync.set in `background.js` and accessing it from `options.js`. Everything is running perfectly fine. I can use the `URLarray` in `options.js` with no problem.
But when I shutdown chrome and reopen it, all the data disappears. Please advice.

**background.js**

```
    save["myKey"] = URLarray;    
    chrome.storage.sync.set(save, function() {
        // console.log('Settings saved');
    });
```

*URLarray is populated as follows:*

```
URLarray.push({website: websiteName, time:0, startTime:0, endTime:0});
```

**options.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('myKey', function (obj) {
        // console.log('myKey', obj);
        x = obj.myKey;
        console.log(x);
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Animated Page Action",
  "description": "This extension adds an animated browser action to the toolbar.",
  "version": "1.2",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "First icon",
    "default_icon": "icon_0.png"

  },

  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": ["tabs","storage"],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: likely an issue with your hardware. try on a different computer.

Comment: Hi @ZigMandel, I did as you say but no success. Can you tell any other way to do this?

Comment: to troubleshoot, try instead saving JSON.stringify(array) and see if that one survives.

Comment: `URLarray` is a simple array so the problem is elsewhere. The posted code isn't enough to diagnose it. Use the devtools debugger to set breakpoints inside the background page script functions and check the actual values of your variables.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953717/google-chrome-extension-chrome-storage-sync-get-not-working

Comment: Not quite sure why you ask this. Your background code never reads from the storage. So when the extension is restarted, your background page doesn't read the old data, but DOES overwrite it with empty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background code (which you don't include here) never actually *reads* data.

It does, however, *write* data, using that snippet you show, which is initialized by an empty array.

So each time you open the extension again, the data in background is empty, and it overwrites the saved data. To fix this, you must first perform initialization of your background `URLarray` from storage.

Comment: I am so thankful to you. I couldn't have figured it out myself. :)